# Having a problem with urls on pandas dataframes (data shown is not data stored)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm having a problem while trying to build a scraper that saves to a dataframe so i can easily visualize what I scraped.

So I'm scraping OLX (the marketplace website) for local car prices (as car have many features, which makes then cool for this kind of stuff) so I can have this dataframe that I can later visualize using stuff like seaborn and whatnot, but I want to be able to put the save the links to the pages so if (let's say) I something cheap I can go and see the ad on the site.

but when I try to save the link to the dataframe it seems to be cut.

```
 row = {'modelo':modelo,
   'marca': marca,
   'ano':ano,
   'preco': preco,
   'kilometragem':kilometragem,
   'transmissao': transmissao,
   'direcao':direcao,
   'motor':motor,
   'combustivel':combustivel,
   'portas':portas,
   'extras':extras,
   'link':link}
print(row['link'])
olx= olx.append(to_df(row))


def to_df(data):
    d = [[data['modelo'],
          data['marca'],
         data['ano'],
         data['preco'],
         data['kilometragem'],
         data['transmissao'],
         data['direcao'],
         data['motor'],
         data['combustivel'],
         data['portas'],
         data['extras'],
         data['link']
         ]]
    #series=pd.Series(d['Finish date'],d['Purpose'],d['Project name'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['modelo', 'marca', 'ano', 'preco', 'kilometragem', 'transmissao','direcao','motor','combustivel','portas','extras','link'])

    return df
```

as you see I build a dataframe around the info and append it to the end of a "master" dataframe, the problem is when I want to check the links on the dataframe this happens:

```
olx['link']

0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
                           ...                        
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
0    https://ce.olx.com.br/fortaleza-e-regiao/autos...
```

the dataframe when saving seems to be cutting.
I checked and it seems to be a problem when making the dataframe in the to_df function as while on the list d the link is intact, but when de dataframe df is generated the link column is cut as seen.

It seems it works like this `olx['link'].values[0]` , but I really need the full link on the df.

I also tried saving it in a table on a base and funnily enough it also have this disparity of no matter how long my link table is it stops on the '...' but when i scroll over or copy it shows the whole link. but i guess this difference would make hard to not have duplicates or something if I wanted to check for duplicates while tracking new additions or something.

what can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following line

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

edit: sorry "-1" may not be supported anymore, so its better to use "None"